# overridden authenticated method in Login Controller doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-5

I'm trying to override the authenticated method in the Login Controller but somehow it isn't working. I just tried to simply dd(); but still it doesn't work.

Below is my function code:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    dd("hi");
}
```

What I actually wish to do is as below, but just for simplicity sake, I have dd(); in the function.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (!$user->verified) {
        auth()->logout();
        return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');
    }
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Whole controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Mail\WelcomeMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'isActive' => '1']))
    {
        return view('homepage');
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request, 'auth.failed_status');
    }
}


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    dd("HI");
  // auth()->logout();
  return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');

// if(!$user->verified)
// {
//   auth()->logout();
//   // Auth::logout();
//   // \Auth::guard('web')->logout();
//   // added logout here
//   return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');
// }
// return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
 }
}
```

Kindly ignore the extra commented code in the authenticated function in the controller.

Comment: try protected function authenticated rather than public

Comment: Did that too. Doesnt work.

Comment: Can you show us the whole controller?

Comment: @ChinLeung - I have posted the controller in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because you are overwriting the login function, hence the authenticated function is never called.

If you take a look at the trait:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

As you can see, the function `sendLoginResponse` is the one that is calling the `authenticated` function.

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Therefore, in your case, it should be something like this, to regenerate the session and clear the attempts:

```
return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
```

Or if you want to skip directly to the **authenticated** function:

```
return $this->authenticated($request, auth()->user());
```

And your function should look like this:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'isActive' => '1']))
    {
        // Updated this line
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);

        // OR this one
        // return $this->authenticated($request, auth()->user());
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request, 'auth.failed_status');
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah. I never gave attention to the login() function. I wasn't aware the authenticated() function was called in login().

Thanks a lot @Chin Leung!

Comment: @Vivek No problem! :)

Comment: You are the best!! :D Thanks!!

Comment: Best! Absolutely the best!