# how to override authenticated() method for a custom guard

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom guard named customer that uses traits from AuthenticateUser.php, when i wanted to override the `authenticated()` method so that the customer must verify account before signing in the method is not executing tried to run data dump no result showed up. So i am wondering do i have to make a route web.php in order to execute the custom guard not sure why the authenticated method not executing.

logincontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\CustomerAuth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use App\Customer;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('customer');
    }

    public function logoutcustomer(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function authenticated(Request $request, $customer)
    {
        if (!$customer->verified) {
            $this->guard()->logout();

            return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');
        }

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        if (Auth::user() || Auth::guard('customer')->user()) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return view('customer-auth.login');
        }
    }

    public function customerLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }

        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson this is on laravel 5.6

Comment: Is this the only LoginController you're using? If not, are you using different routes for different logins?

Comment: @RossWilson i have two loginController the default when you run php artisan make:auth and this one. the other login controller works i can modifiy the authenticated() user login controller but i can't modify this one on the customer login controller.

Comment: Are the routes different? If so, is the form action for the customer login for definitely pointing to the correct route? Also, what exactly did you do to run the "data dump"?

Comment: @RossWilson yes there are for customer i created a Route group with the prefix of customer and have login and register and reset password. The other login users uses the default Auth::routes();

Comment: Please can you add the code for your `customer-auth.login` view?

Comment: @RossWilson added my login.blade.php there are two login types sharing the same screen customer and merchants. also i wanted to data dump when a customer signup boolean value return 0 and when they verify return 1.

Comment: @RossWilson i think i know the issue look at my logincontroller https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50474763/overridden-authenticated-method-in-login-controller-doesnt-work

Comment: Ah ha, yep that'll do it. Glad you figured it out! :)

Comment: @RossWilson thx! very much